# What is the interpretation of the weights in the GMM?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution, model-based-clustering

GMM is $p(x|\theta) = w_1 \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_1,\,\sigma_1^{2})\ + w_2 \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_2,\,\sigma_2^{2}) + w_3 \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_3,\,\sigma_3^{2})\,$
What is the interpretation of the weights here?
Do they mean "How confident the model is about a particular gaussian(ex, $\mathcal{N}(x|\mu_2,\,\sigma_2^{2})\,$ )"?
And Why is the model confident about specific gaussian?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one quite intuitive interpretation. These weights are non-negative and sum up to $1$. So, it's like saying we have a RV that comes from $\mathcal{N_1}$ with probability $w_1$, from $\mathcal{N_2}$ with probability $w_2$, and from $\mathcal{N_3}$ with probability $w_3$. By the way, this way of thinking is not a special property of GMMs, but several kinds of mixtures.

Answer (score 1):

The weights are the "responsibilities".

They are normalized to 1, which is motivated from the *assumption* that all the data *has* to be explained by the model, then using the law of total probability. So in that sense they are not just weights - they are the probabilities of the point being part of the cluster.